# How to implement rollback of multi-statement transaction in SQLite?

Tags: sql, sqlite, transactions, rollback

Using sqlite3 3.43.2 on macOS, I feed the following into an otherwise-empty in-memory database:

```
.mode markdown
.headers on

create table job(
    name text not null,
    billable real not null,
    check(billable > 0.0) on conflict abort
);

begin transaction;
insert into job values ("calibrate", 1.5);
insert into job values ("reset", -0.5);
insert into job values ("clean", 0.5);
commit;

select * from job;
```

I expect to get nothing from the final `select` because there is a `check` violation in the second `insert` inside a transaction, but instead the other two `insert` statements have executed:

```
Runtime error near line 12: CHECK constraint failed: billable > 0.0 (19)
|   name    | billable |
|-----------|----------|
| calibrate | 1.5      |
| clean     | 0.5      |
```

1. Removing `on conflict abort` from the table definition does not change this behavior.
2. Replacing `on conflict abort` with `on conflict rollback` in the table definition does not change this behavior.

All right: let's move the error handling to the `insert` statements. In a fresh in-memory database:

```
create table job(
    name text not null,
    billable real not null,
    check(billable > 0.0)
);

begin transaction;
insert or rollback into job values ("calibrate", 1.5);
insert or rollback into job values ("reset", -0.5);
insert or rollback into job values ("clean", 0.5);
commit;

select * from job;
```

The output is:

```
Runtime error near line 12: CHECK constraint failed: billable > 0.0 (19)
Runtime error near line 14: cannot commit - no transaction is active
| name  | billable |
|-------|----------|
| clean | 0.5      |
```

which shows that SQLite carried on and executed the third statement inside the transaction (which inserted `clean`) *after* the error in the second statement in that transaction. I expected that when the error occurred in the second statement, the entire transaction would abort, i.e., SQLite wouldn't even try the third `insert`. (My mental model is exceptions being raised and caught in programming languages.)

Finally, in yet another fresh database:

```
insert or rollback into job values ("calibrate", 1.5);
insert or rollback into job values ("reset", -0.5);
insert or rollback into job values ("clean", 0.5);
```

produces:

```
Runtime error near line 11: CHECK constraint failed: billable > 0.0 (19)
|   name    | billable |
|-----------|----------|
| calibrate | 1.5      |
| clean     | 0.5      |
```

which is what I expect, but not what I want.

Is there a way to create a true multi-statement transaction in SQLite? If so, what is the syntax? I want something like:

```
-- this is not valid SQLite syntax
begin transaction;
insert into job values ("calibrate", 1.5);
insert into job values ("reset", -0.5);
insert into job values ("clean", 0.5);
commit or rollback;
```

but as noted, that doesn't parse. The desired effect is that if *any* statement inside the transaction fails, the *entire* transaction is rolled back.

Comment: After the failed insert causes the current transaction to roll back, the next insert happens in a new transaction. In whatever language you're using sqlite from, you need to start a transaction, run each insert and if it failed, skip any later inserts that should be part of the same transaction.

Comment: In the sqlite3 command line program, setting `.bail on` is probably the closest you can get.

Comment: I was hoping I could do what I wanted in pure SQL, but even in Python, and with `autocommit=False` on the connection, it seems that there's no way to create a multi-statement transaction. If I want to insert records into two different tables indivisibly (either both tables are updated or neither), I seem to be stuck, which makes me believe I must be missing something (?).

Answer (score 1):

Is this maybe an alternative acceptable behavior?

```sql
create table job(
    name text not null,
    billable real not null,
    check(billable > 0.0)
);

begin transaction;
insert into job values ("calibrate", 1.5), ("reset", -0.5), ("clean", 0.5);
commit;

-- Runtime error: CHECK constraint failed: billable > 0.0 (19)
select * from job; -- zero rows
```

edit for clarity; you need to decide how to handle successful statements:

```sql
begin transaction;
insert into job values ("calibrate", 1.5);
insert into job values ("reset", -0.5);
-- error: CHECK constraint failed: billable > 0.0 (19)
insert into job values ("clean", 0.5);
rollback;
select * from job; -- zero rows
```

or

```sql
begin transaction;
insert into job values ("calibrate", 1.5);
insert into job values ("reset", -0.5);
-- error: CHECK constraint failed: billable > 0.0 (19)
insert into job values ("clean", 0.5);
commit;
select * from job;
/*
calibrate|1.5
clean|0.5
*/
```

Comment: Inserting multiple values into a single table in a single statement works [had to insert "into" between "insert" and "job"], but it works just as well *without* `begin transaction` and `commit`. I'd be happy to do this if I had just one table, but what if I want to insert records into two different tables indivisibly? thanks

Comment: (Add back the deleted `into`, apologies). Not sure what you are trying to achieve now -  mabye clarify your post a bit. Do you want all-or-nothing across multiple statements or do you want only failed statements to rollback but successful statements to commit? Also keep in mind that the behavior at the command line might be a bit more opiniated that using an api wrapper. (See this note on autocommit)[https://sqlite.org/c3ref/get_autocommit.html]. Programatically I issue a `BEGIN`, check the sqlite return status of each statement, and then `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK` accordingly.

Comment: Maybe just to clarify a bit more, at the command line, if you start with `BEGIN`, have multiple statements, some of which fail, sqlite appears to automatically rollback the failed statements. The successful statements are up for grabs, now. You choose to `COMMIT` them or `ROLLBACK`. When using the api, it's somewhat similar, except you can check the success of each statement to programatically decide if you want to `COMMIT` successful statements or `ROLLBACK` all. Your api wrapper might decide for you if it detects an unhandled error status on the connection.